# M2 | Convert language to French for API response

Tags: magento2, rest-api, language, conversion, vuejs

I have a custom API whose response message is in English. I wanted to convert it to french language when it reaches the frontend. e.g now my API is sending a message as:

```
if (!strcmp($gcode,$giftcode)) {
         result=array(); 
         $result['message']='Gift card already redeemed';
         echo json_encode($result);
         exit;
   }
```

My backend is Magento 2(English) and the frontend is in Vue Js storefront (French language).

I have used some built-in APIs also, so how can I change their language.

Or the language will be changed by Vue Js storefront when any API (built-in, custom) response is received. Or it should be handled in the backend (Magento 2)?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change `'Gift card already redeemed'` to `__('Gift card already redeemed')` then you need to add store code before `/V1/rest` 
e.g

> store_code/V1/rest